# Longest Increasing Subsequence variations dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, lis

I have this question:

Given the following:

`A = [9,6,9,3,8,9,2,0,4,12]`
`C = [r,g,r,g,r,g,r,r,r,g]`

Where 
 - `r` = red 
 - `g` = green

This list represent the color of the number in the same index in array `A`  i.e. `A[0] = 9 = red, A[1] = 6 = green, ...`

We need to pick a number `N` to start, if the number is `green` we can only move right (by any numbers) to a number that are `>=N` greater than the current one.

If the number `N` is `red`, we can only move left (by any numbers) to a number that are `>=N` greater than the current one.

**Objective**: find the longest sequence of moves possible, return the indices of the path. If there are multiple subsequences of the same length that are longest, return anyone:

Example 1:

```
    A = [9,6,9,3,8,9,2,0,4,12]
    C = [r,g,r,g,r,g,r,r,r,g]
    output: [7,6,3,8,1,4,0]
```

Example 2:

```
    A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10]
    C =[r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r]
    output:[7]
```

Example 3:

```
    A = [5,3,2,0,24,9,20]
    C = [g,g,g,g,r,r,g]
    output: [0,5,4]
```

Current idea of my algorithm:

Consider possible moves for every element in `A`, for the first example, `A[0] = 9` = `red`.

As there is no left elements, there is only `1` move (choose `A[0]`).

So, `OPT[0] = 1`. For `A[1] = 6` = `green`. 
Possible move are: `A[2]= 9`, `A[4] = 8`, `A[5] = 9`, `A[9] =12`.

Recursion is `OPT[i] = max{1, 1+ OPT[j]}`  where `j` is the next possible move.

Am I on the right track using dynamic programming? The runtime is `O(n²)` isn't it?

Comment: You are on a workable track and the runtime is `O(n^2)` if correctly implemented.

Comment: The output for example 1 seems incorrect. It seems that it should be [7,6,3,8,1,4,2,0] because we are allowed to continue to equal numbers (9 <- 9 <- 8)